# Dynamically adding #anchors to links via css media queries and generated content

Tags: css

In each of my pages, just above the main content block, I have a named anchor item like so:

```
<a id="jump"></a>
```

My site's css contains a media query that resets styles when the browser width is less than 770 (iPad Portrait). I'd like to insert css into this query branch so that all my main site links are automatically appended with a reference to that anchor like so:

```
<a href="about-us/#jump">About Us</a>
```

Can I do this with generated content via CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS 3 specifies powerful [generate/replace capabilitie](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/)s but I am pretty sure you can't modify the attributes of an existing tag using only CSS.

It is possible to read the value of an attribute and include that value in generated content, such as:

```
[href]::after { content: footnote; }
[href]::after::alternate { content: attr(href); }
```

However, I don't think that all the pieces are there to get the behavior you want.

Alternatively, you could include the anchor in *all* of your links, and then positioned the anchor differently depending on your media query? If the screen was wide, the anchor could be at the very top of the page. If the width was less than 770, the anchor would be positioned further down the page.

Comment: That's an interesting approach Tim. I'd much prefer to do it only for those that need it, but you may be right about the inability to append to the hrefs

Comment: I agree with only doing it when necessary. I updated my answer with a little more information about advanced CSS 3 content generation, although I still don't think that there is a way to do what you want.